# How to have the kernel print a stacktrace when sending a Hardware NMI

Tags: linux, hardware, nmi

I have Qemu VMs running FreeBSD, Windows and Linux, and I can send them a hardware NMI via the Qemu monitor.

`qm monitor 100
Entering Qemu Monitor for VM 100 - type 'help' for help
qm> help nmi
nmi  -- inject an NMI`

When inkecting the NMI to a Windows VM, I get the message is saving a crash dump, and this reboot the VM.

On Linux I get the message

`[26731.911302] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 31 on CPU 0.
[26731.911303] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?
[26731.911304] Dazed and confused, but trying to continue`

How to get the kernel to print a stack trace on the console instead of only this message ?

I would need this to debug VMs hanging because of very slow IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, the way to do this on Linux is via a sysctl

```
sysctl kernel.unknown_nmi_panic=1
```

after setting this parameter, I get a stack strace on the console (a serial console in my case but I don't think it matters here.

`[  253.697690] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P           O    4.13.4-1-pve #1
[  253.697691] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.10.2-0-g5f4c7b1-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/01/2014
[  253.697691] Call Trace:
[  253.697692]  <NMI>
[  253.697697]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[  253.697699]  panic+0xe4/0x23d
[  253.697700]  nmi_panic+0x39/0x40
[  253.697703]  unknown_nmi_error+0x77/0x90
[  253.697704]  default_do_nmi+0xe7/0x110
[  253.697705]  do_nmi+0x119/0x180
[  253.697707]  end_repeat_nmi+0x1a/0x1e
[  253.697710] RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[  253.697711] RSP: 0018:ffffffffb0803de0 EFLAGS: 00000246
[  253.697712] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffb0810480 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  253.697712] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  253.697713] RBP: ffffffffb0803de0 R08: 0000006e031e1414 R09: ffffb9a70831fd00
[  253.697714] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 8000003b10fbadff R12: 0000000000000000
[  253.697714] R13: ffffffffb0810480 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[  253.697717]  ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[  253.697718]  ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[  253.697718]  </NMI>
[  253.697720]  default_idle+0x20/0x100
[  253.697721]  arch_cpu_idle+0xf/0x20
[  253.697723]  default_idle_call+0x23/0x30
[  253.697725]  do_idle+0x17c/0x200
[  253.697726]  cpu_startup_entry+0x73/0x80
[  253.697727]  rest_init+0xbc/0xc0
[  253.697733]  start_kernel+0x4d2/0x4f3
[  253.697745]  ? early_idt_handler_array+0x120/0x120
[  253.697746]  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x26
[  253.697747]  x86_64_start_kernel+0x14f/0x172
[  253.697748]  secondary_startup_64+0x9f/0x9f
[  253.697875] Kernel Offset: 0x2ea00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)`